# Is use of present continuous grammatically acceptable in this sentence?

Tags: present-continuous

I made the following sentence -

> "*If he continues to work hard, he will have gained a lot of
> experience by the time he turns 35.*".

A person has insisted that there is one more correct form of this sentence, namely -

> "***If he is continuing to work hard**, he will have gained a lot of
> experience by the time he turns 35.*".

It strikes me that the latter sentence is grammatically incorrect, as the context of speech here is a regularly occurring action (work hard over a period of time), not a fully continuous one (the work that one does at the current moment). Is that right?

Comment: They're both correct. The second version means that he must still be working hard at the time he turns 35. The first version means that he must continue to work hard now, but it doesn't have to continue all the way to 35.

Comment: The second one could also mean that he should be continuing to work hard now, but not necessarily in the future. But that's doesn't match the conclusion very well, since he's already gained the experience rather than "will have gained experience".

Comment: The second one sounds really wrong to me; *is continuing* talks about the present, and *will have gained* talks about the future, so there's a mismatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latter sentence is incorrect, but this is not explained by reference to the context of habitual actions; instead, this incorrectness stems from the fact that "*in many cases the progressive is unacceptable with stative verbs*", and "to continue" is a stative verb.

> *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*
> **4.26**      **State, event, and habit with the progressive**
>
> The three verb senses of state, event, and habit are differently interpreted
> with the progressive:
>
> (a) STATE PROGRESSIVE
> In many cases […] the progressive is unacceptable with stative verbs:
> • We own a house in the country.
> • *We are owning a house in the country. (*The asterisk means "unacceptable"*)
> • Sam's wife was being well-dressed.
> This can be explained, in part, by the observation that stative verb meanings
> are inimical to the idea that some phenomenon is 'in progress'. States are
> 'like-parted' in that every segment of a state has the same character as any
> other segment: no progress is made. (Contrast *We are building a house in the
> country*.) Where the progressive does occur, it is felt to imply temporariness
> rather than permanence:
> • We are living in the country. [temporary residence]
> • We live in the country. [permanent residence]
> […]